# how to change language from german to english in vs code database explorer view with mssql extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings, vscode-extensions

I have installed Visual Studio Code and added the SQL Server (mssql) extension.
When connecting to a database the explorer view shows all object names in the tree in german, which is the default language on my Windows 10 PC.
All other elements oof VS Code are displayed in english.
How do I change the settings etc. that the explorer view for the Database also shows english text.

I had changed the language in the argv.json file as follows and restarted VS Code:

```json
// Display language of VSCode
    "locale": "en",
```

but with no effect. The explorer view still displayed the names in german again.